# Drupal 7 PDOException: (possibly a max_packet_size issue?)

Tags: mysql, drupal

After saving a View i got this error come up on all pages in Drupal 7. After some research i think it's a problem with the "max allowed packet" in Mysql being set too low...currently 68MB. I have requested it be set to 250MB. But any further diagnosis of the problem would be welcomed.

```
Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception.

Original

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: SELECT format, type, language FROM {date_format_locale}; Array ( ) in system_date_format_locale() (line 3650 of /home/mysite/public_html/beta1/modules/system/system.module).

Additional

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: INSERT INTO {watchdog} (uid, type, message, variables, severity, link, location, referer, hostname, timestamp) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8, :db_insert_placeholder_9); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] =&gt; 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] =&gt; php [:db_insert_placeholder_2] =&gt; %type: !message in %function (line %line of %file). [:db_insert_placeholder_3] =&gt; a:6:{s:5:&quot;%type&quot;;s:12:&quot;PDOException&quot;;s:8:&quot;!message&quot;;s:132:&quot;SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: SELECT format, type, language FROM {date_format_locale}; Array ( ) &quot;;s:9:&quot;%function&quot;;s:27:&quot;system_date_format_locale()&quot;;s:5:&quot;%file&quot;;s:61:&quot;/home/mysite/public_html/beta1/modules/system/system.module&quot;;s:5:&quot;%line&quot;;i:3650;s:14:&quot;severity_level&quot;;i:3;} [:db_insert_placeholder_4] =&gt; 3 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] =&gt; [:db_insert_placeholder_6] =&gt; http://beta1.mysite.co.uk/ [:db_insert_placeholder_7] =&gt; [:db_insert_placeholder_8] =&gt; 83.244.234.228 [:db_insert_placeholder_9] =&gt; 1352306457 ) in dblog_watchdog() (line 157 of /home/mysite/public_html/beta1/modules/dblog/dblog.module).

Uncaught exception thrown in session handler.

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away in _drupal_session_write() (line 206 of /home/mysite/public_html/beta1/includes/session.inc).
```

thanks

lee

Comment: I'd bet my house on `max_packet_size` being the problem here, the cache strings that the Views module generates are huge. [You're not alone](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32642/nasty-database-error-when-adding-any-type-of-content/32645#32645)

Comment: Hi Clive, i think that was definitely partly to do with it but the guys at PlatinumServerManagement, in order to fix the issue they increased the wait-timeout value in mysql configuration file. There was a particular view i had created which was pulling back way too many results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix this issue the guys at PlatinumServerManagement.com increased the wait-timeout value in mysql configuration file.

Lee